# Resurrection via Psions using their Psicrystal

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, resurrection

I vaguely remember psicrystals holding the soul of the Psion upon death and escaping to a safe location to regrow a new body for its owner where the crystal itself is part of the new body. Was this done with feat or Class specific Psion?

Answer (score 1):

### The Psicrystal Imprinter PrC has this ability

The Psicrystal Imprinter gains the class feature [Essence Crystal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-prestige-classes/psicrystal-imprinter#TOC-Essence-Crystal-Su-) at level 9 (of the PrC, minimum character level 14) that does what you're looking for.

--

This seems to be, at least partially, based on the 3.5e [Psicrystal Savant](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Psicrystal_Savant_(3.5e_Prestige_Class)) which gains Psicrystal Phylactery at level 7 (minimum character level 10... unless you cheese to Manifest 2nd level Powers early).

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I remember reading way back then. Sadly there is no Pathfinder equivalent.